# Can't boot from aomei uefi boot stick

Tags: windows-10, boot, ntfs, uefi, fat32

I am not able to boot from my previously used legacy aomei boot stick since our new notebooks are uefi only. So I tried creating a new uefi boot stick. Unfortunately I was/am not able to see any available boot devices in the boot menu expect the internal m.2 ssd. I was able to see the old legacy boot stick but obviously I could not see the internal drive. The only way I was able to see the boot stick in the boot menu was when I created a uefi boot stick with ntfs not fat32, but then I was not able to boot from the stick I was just able to see it in the boot menu. Is there any way I can boot from a ntfs boot stick or is there a way how I can see the usually used fat32 sticks?
I am using a Dell Latitude 5510

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem. I just created a normal aomei uefi boot stick with rufus (GPT, Fat32). The only things you must do in uefi on the notebook is to deactivate secure boot, set secure boot to audit mode and activate AHCI Mode at Sata operation.
After I restorde my image i activated secure boot again and everything worked fine.